New Beta Theme Launched
Your site looks a bit different today. Yes, we are getting rid of the 'Sketchy' look and replacing it with a more-polished and finished design for sites in beta.
You can read more about the redesign of our Beta theme on our blog entry.
Please note: This will not affect your "graduation" status in any way. When your site is due for graduation, it will get its final(real) site design and branding.
If you're still seeing the old favicon, please do a hard browser refresh. (Although sometimes it may take Chrome a while to load the new image).
If you see any CSS or styling issues, please report it in this post I created on Meta Stack Overflow. It will be easier for me to track all the bug reports there.

Please see my edit. :)

Oh I've seen this on Judaism SE I think! :D Nice one! I like the polished version actually. :)
Good job, Jin! I can't wait for the final design. We're still... behind but let's hope that comes soon. :)
Edit: Jin, would it be possible to change the favicon from "CN" to "ZH" which is, probably, better?

For our foreign language Beta sites(German, French, Japanese and Spanish) I go by the standard and common abbreviations, e.g. De, Fr, Jp, and Es. I picked Cn (previously Chn) because it's the most common. I'm aware of the "ZH" abbreviation, but it's so rarely used that's why I didn't pick it.

I see. Ok then. We'll stick to the CN. :)
